# How To Add Margin in Section for disappear by fixed header after click on tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've searched all over and found lot of "solutions" but none of them seem to work for me. I'm a new developer.

I have a fixed header. The header is fixed when scrolling.

how to achieve this, Section are disappear after click on sidebar tabs list..

### At Present Result..

[image]

### We Want This Result..

[image]

how do this one with JAVA OR CSS OR ANY OTHER WAY?

```css
*{ 
    margin: 0px;
}

#sidebar {
  position:fixed; 
  height: 100%;
  width:10%;
  margin: 0px;  
  background: lightblue; 
  border-radius: 7px;  
}


#rightSideWrapper {
    width: 90%; 
    float: right;
    background: black;  
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #d8b39d;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
section {
    height: 200px;
    order: 2;
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 31px;
    font-weight: 900;
}


section, footer {
     background: lightgray; 
     border-radius: 7px; 
     margin: 5px; 
     padding: 20px;
}


footer {
    height: 20px;
    order: 3;
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #d297c0;
    
}


/*Side Menu CSS */

.codehim-menu {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #438D80;
    padding: 7px 1px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    transition: .3s;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}
.codehim-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    
}
ul.codehim-menu{
   list-style: none;
}
.codehim-menu > li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;   
} 
.codehim-menu > li > a {
  height: 25px;
  display: block; 
  font-size: 17px;  
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 3px 1px 3px 10px;
  color: #08c;
  outline: 0;
  
}
.codehim-menu > li > a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #fff;
}
.codehim-menu > li.active > a, 
.codehim-menu > li > a:active, 
.codehim-menu > .dropdown:hover > a {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);  
}
.trigger {
    display: none;
}

.divider {
    height: 25px;
    margin: 4px 0px 10px;
    padding: 1px 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5f6975;
}
.codehim-menu .divider {
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-code">

   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="menu-trigger" class="trigger">
    <label for="menu-trigger">
       <div class="codehim-menu-trigger"></div>
   </label>

   <nav>
     <ul class="codehim-menu">
      <li> <a href="#A">Tabs A</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#B">Tabs B</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#C">Tabs C</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#D">Tabs D</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#E">Tabs E</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#F">Tabs F</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#G">Tabs G</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#H">Tabs H</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#I">Tabs I</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#J">Tabs J</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#K">Tabs K</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#L">Tabs L</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div> 
      

      

<div id="rightSideWrapper">
<header> Header Are Here</header>
                            
        
<section><div id="A">Section Content A</div></section>
        
<section><div id="B">Section Content B</div></section>
        
<section><div id="C">Section Content C</div></section>
        
<section><div id="D">Section Content D</div></section>
        
<section><div id="E">Section Content E</div></section>
        
<section><div id="F">Section Content F</div></section>
                
<section><div id="G">Section Content G</div></section>
                
<section><div id="H">Section Content H</div></section>
                
<section><div id="I">Section Content I</div></section>
                
<section><div id="J">Section Content J</div></section>

<section><div id="K">Section Content I</div></section>
                
<section><div id="L">Section Content J</div></section>

        
<footer> Footer Are Here</footer>

</div>
```

Comment: Use `position: sticky` and `top: 0` instead of  `position: fixed` in `header`.

Comment: but position: fixed in header are important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved using *JavaScript*. I have modified your code a bit. I have added `data-href` attributes instead of `href` since it overrode the JavaScript's Scroll.
I have included comments in JS Code, for you to understand, what have I done.

```js
let tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".codehim-menu li a");  //Select all anchor elements

tabs.forEach((tab)=>{
  tab.onclick= function(){
    let el = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.href).offsetTop; //getting the posiiton of each section
    let pos = el - document.querySelector("header").offsetHeight-25; //Subtracting the height of header from position of each section with some extra offset (i.e 25)
    window.scrollTo(0, pos); //Scrolling the window to generated position
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0px;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#rightSideWrapper {
  width: 90%;
  float: right;
  background: black;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #d8b39d;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

section {
  height: 200px;
  order: 2;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 31px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

section,
footer {
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}

footer {
  height: 20px;
  order: 3;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #d297c0;
}


/*Side Menu CSS */

.codehim-menu {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #438D80;
  padding: 7px 1px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  transition: .3s;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}

.codehim-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
}

ul.codehim-menu {
  list-style: none;
}

.codehim-menu>li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.codehim-menu>li>a {
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 3px 1px 3px 10px;
  color: #08c;
  outline: 0;
}

.codehim-menu>li>a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #fff;
}

.codehim-menu>li.active>a,
.codehim-menu>li>a:active,
.codehim-menu>.dropdown:hover>a {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.trigger {
  display: none;
}

.divider {
  height: 25px;
  margin: 4px 0px 10px;
  padding: 1px 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5f6975;
}

.codehim-menu .divider {
  margin-top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-code">

  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="menu-trigger" class="trigger">
  <label for="menu-trigger">
       <div class="codehim-menu-trigger"></div>
   </label>

  <nav>
    <ul class="codehim-menu">
      <li> <a data-href="#A">Tabs A</a></li>
      <li> <a data-href="#B">Tabs B</a></li>
      <li> <a data-href="#C">Tabs C</a></li>
      <li> <a data-href="#D">Tabs D</a></li>
      <li> <a data-href="#E">Tabs E</a></li>
      <li> <a data-href="#F">Tabs F</a></li>
      <li> <a data-href="#G">Tabs G</a></li>
      <li> <a data-href="#H">Tabs H</a></li>
      <li> <a data-href="#I">Tabs I</a></li>
      <li> <a data-href="#J">Tabs J</a></li>
      <li> <a data-href="#K">Tabs K</a></li>
      <li> <a data-href="#L">Tabs L</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>




<div id="rightSideWrapper">
  <header> Header Are Here</header>


  <section>
    <div id="A">Section Content A</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="B">Section Content B</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="C">Section Content C</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="D">Section Content D</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="E">Section Content E</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="F">Section Content F</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="G">Section Content G</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="H">Section Content H</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="I">Section Content I</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="J">Section Content J</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="K">Section Content I</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="L">Section Content J</div>
  </section>


  <footer> Footer Are Here</footer>

</div>
```